# Form designer in Delphi can't find DLL

Tags: postgresql, delphi, dll, path, libpq

Where to put DLLs so that Delphi could find them at design time?

I am editing properties of TDBChart at design time in Delphi. When I attempt to set data source for Series, it complains about absence of libpq.dll which does exist and is in PATH.

The problem is that in PATH exists another (64-bit) version, so the 32-bit DLLs should be shipped with application and be available not only at run-time but at design time too.

Answer (score 0):

libpq.dll itself depends on a series of other DLL's, could you check if they are available in the same folder libpq.dll is in?

```
ssleay32.dll
libeay32.dll
libiconv-2.dll
libintl-8.dll
```

Comment: Yes, I am copying all them with my app's exe file, but for design time I found the only possible solution: to copy them to some folder on driver c:\ and make it appear in PATH before other folders, but I would like to copy them somewhere inside of my project,

Comment: Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx